# how to check and uncheck all asp.net checkbox on single checkbox check?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to check and uncheck all asp.net checkbox on single checkbox check ?

I have 5 asp.net checkbox on webform i want when 1 single checkbox checked then all checkbox will be cchecked and if checkbox is unchecked then all checkb ox will be unchecked ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little code snippet :

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkStatu" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <hr />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes(this,'chkStatu');"
            Text="SelectAll" />
```

and js

```
 function SelectAllCheckboxes(spanChk,str)
    {
        // Added as ASPX uses SPAN for checkbox
        var oItem = spanChk.children;
        var theBox=(spanChk.type=="checkbox")?spanChk:spanChk.children.item[0];
        var control;

        xState=theBox.checked;
        elm=theBox.form.elements;

        for(i=0;i<elm.length;i++)
            if(elm[i].type=="checkbox" && elm[i].id!=theBox.id)
            {
            control =elm[i].id.indexOf(str);
            if(elm[i].checked!=xState && control != -1)
             {
                elm[i].click();
             }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Check or UnCheck all the checkboxes based on header checkbox and change row color 
Protected Sub ckHeader_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim chHeader As CheckBox
    Dim chSelect As CheckBox
    Dim cHeader As Boolean
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim gvr As DataGridItem
    count = -1
    Try
        chHeader = CType(CMSgrid.Controls(0).Controls(1).FindControl("ckHeader"), CheckBox)
        cHeader = chHeader.Checked
        For Each gvr In CMSgrid.Items
            count = count + 1
            chSelect = CType(gvr.FindControl("ckSelect"), CheckBox)
            If (cHeader = True) Then
                gvr.BackColor = Color.Gold
                gvr.ForeColor = Color.Black
                chSelect.Checked = True
            Else
                If (count Mod 2) = 0 Then
                    gvr.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
                    gvr.ForeColor = Color.Black
                Else
                    gvr.BackColor = Color.PaleGoldenrod
                    gvr.ForeColor = Color.Black
                End If
                chSelect.Checked = False
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        UserMsgBox(ex.Message)
        WriteToLog(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Where `chHeader` indicates the main checkbox.

By inspecting the above code, hopefully you can understand how to make it.